# Hive - Parquet format - OR clause in where not working as expected

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am creating a table and inserting data like below

```
CREATE TABLE `mydb.mytable`(
  `seq_num` decimal(18,0),
  `ins_upd_flag` char(1)
  )
stored as parquet;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mydb.mytable
SELECT 10457 SEQ_NUM,'I' INS_UPD_FLAG UNION ALL 
SELECT 10462,'I' UNION ALL 
SELECT 10461,'I' UNION ALL 
SELECT 10460,'I' UNION ALL 
SELECT 10459,'I' UNION ALL 
SELECT 10456,'I' UNION ALL 
SELECT 10458,'I';
```

As you can see above, the second column value is just 'I' and it does not have any extra characters.

When I run the following query, it does not result anything

```
SELECT T.*, length(INS_UPD_FLAG), length(trim(INS_UPD_FLAG))
FROM mydb.mytable T
WHERE SEQ_NUM <> 0  OR INS_UPD_FLAG <> 'I' ;
```

However, if I run the below query it returns all the inserted rows as expected

```
SELECT T.*, length(INS_UPD_FLAG), length(trim(INS_UPD_FLAG)) -- both length =1
FROM mydb.mytable T
WHERE SEQ_NUM <> 0 OR TRIM(INS_UPD_FLAG) <> 'I' ;
```

Any explanation on why this is happening and how to resolve the same? I need the results without using trim

Please note that this issue is happening only with OR condition. If I run the below query, I am getting results

```
SELECT T.*, length(INS_UPD_FLAG), length(trim(INS_UPD_FLAG))
FROM mydb.mytable T
WHERE SEQ_NUM <> 0 and  INS_UPD_FLAG = 'I' ;
```

Also, if I create table with ORC or Text Format, I am getting results without trim.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to re-pro your issue and getting same results as you have explained.

I ran a query to see what exactly your where condition is producing:

```
SELECT
  T.*,
  length(INS_UPD_FLAG),
  length(trim(INS_UPD_FLAG)),
  SEQ_NUM <> 0,
  INS_UPD_FLAG = 'I',
  SEQ_NUM <> 0 or INS_UPD_FLAG = 'I'
FROM mydb.mytable T
```

and results are as following:

```
|seq_num|ins_upd_flag|_c1|_c2|_c3 |_c4 |_c5 |
|10457  |I           |1  |1  |true|true|true|
|10462  |I           |1  |1  |true|true|true|
|10461  |I           |1  |1  |true|true|true|
|10460  |I           |1  |1  |true|true|true|
|10459  |I           |1  |1  |true|true|true|
|10456  |I           |1  |1  |true|true|true|
|10458  |I           |1  |1  |true|true|true|
```

As you can see it is returning `true` for your join condition.

Out of curiosity, I wrapped the where condition around `()` and got the results without trim.

```
SELECT
  T.*,
  length(INS_UPD_FLAG),
  length(trim(INS_UPD_FLAG)),
  SEQ_NUM <> 0,
  INS_UPD_FLAG = 'I',
  SEQ_NUM <> 0 or INS_UPD_FLAG = 'I'
FROM mydb.mytable T
where (SEQ_NUM <> 0 or INS_UPD_FLAG = 'I')
```

Results: Same as previous query.

I am using Hive 1.2.1000 via Hue 2.6.1-227.

I don't know what magic `()` is doing and why query is not working without it.

Comment: Good finding. Unfortunately, the brackets '()' does not do anything in my version of hive (Hive 1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292 on HDP). This looks like a bug with Hive 1.2

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that I am not sure why you aren't seeing the expected results. I ran a very similar test, below, and received the expected results. What version of Hive are you on? I did the same tests on hive-1.1.0+cdh5.13.3+1307 (Cloudera distro w/v5.13):

```
CREATE TABLE test_cond_parq
(
 seq_num decimal(10,0),
 ind string
)
STORED AS PARQUET;

INSERT INTO TABLE test_cond_parq
SELECT 10457, 'I' UNION ALL
SELECT 10458, 'I'
;
```

Then I ran the following query, similar to yours above...

```
SELECT *, LENGTH(ind) len_ind, LENGTH(TRIM(ind)) len_trim_ind
FROM test_cond_parq
WHERE seq_num <> 0 OR ind <> 'I';
```

This returned the following results:

```
10457 | I | 1 | 1
10458 | I | 1 | 1
```

Comment: I am using Hive 1.2.1000.2.6.5.0-292

Comment: Thank you for trying it out. I am surprised why it is not working in the version I am using.

Comment: NP. What SQL editor are you running your test in? I did it in HUE so it could perhaps be related to that?

Answer (score 0):

may i know reason why you dont want to use the trim function.As hadoop stores the data in files there  is alot of chances that it can add the space while inserting.i faced this issue a lot of time while using parque format.it depends sometimes you face it some time you wont face it.
    whatever it is can you run you query only based on this condition 
    SELECT T.*, length(INS_UPD_FLAG), length(trim(INS_UPD_FLAG))
    FROM mydb.mytable T
    WHERE SEQ_NUM <> 0

```
if it is not returning anything the way data inserted is wrong..please try it let me know
```

Comment: I do not want to use trim because I am having a similar char column as partitioned column and I am not sure if a condition with trim(partitioned_column) will be used for predicate push down

Comment: *I am not sure trim(partitioned_column) will be used for partition scan